# nginx - dns resolution in njs

Tags: nginx, node.js

I need to solve a simple DNS query using njs in nginx.

I've searched but it seems that there isn't a 'native' function for doing this.

So I'm trying to use `dns-lookup` module for node.js
I've installed it using `npm install dns-lookup`, then I've tried to use it in my njs script, with something like:

```
var lookup = require('dns-lookup');
ip = lookup.resolve(hostname);
```

But when I run this script I receive an error:

```
[error] 13555#13555: *124 js exception: Error: Cannot find module "dns-lookup"
```

1st question, is it right what I'm doing? How can I load an external module in my js file?

2nd question, do you know how to solve? And/or is there a better way for do a DNS resolution?

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847446/nginx-njs-solve-dns) here in stackoverflow but without answers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be `require('dns');`? See https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns

Comment: @digijay I've tried also to use dns (I forgot to mention on my question) but I got the same error. It seem a generic issue on loading an external module in njs. I've tried also to load them using the full path but with the same result. Not sure if it's a limitation of njs, I cannot find documentation about this